# Inconsistency in JSON.stringify in console and Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Following the comments, I have rephrased the whole question providing the full cloud function context.

```js
exports.handler = (snap, context, db) => {
  try {
    const data = snap.data()

    const value1 = data.value1
    const value2 = data.value2
    const value3 = data.value3

    const docRef = db.doc(`items/list`)

    return docRef
      .get()
      .then(docSnap => {
        if (docSnap.exists) {
          const list = JSON.parse(docSnap.get('list'))
          const newList = [...list, {
            value1: value1,
            value2: value2,
            value3: value3,
          }]
          return docRef
            .update({ list: JSON.stringify(newList) })
            .then(() => {
              return { msg: 'success' }
            })
            .catch(error => {
              return { msg: error }
            })
        } else {
          const newList = [{
            value1: value1,
            value2: value2,
            value3: value3,
          }]
          return docRef
            .update({ list: JSON.stringify(newList) })
            .then(() => {
              return { msg: 'success' }
            })
            .catch(error => {
              return { msg: error }
            })
        }
      })
  } catch (error) {
    return { msg: error }
  }
}
```

The function is above. It runs when there is a new document created in the `items` collection.

```js
exports.onCreateListItem = functions
    .firestore
    .document(`items/{id}`)
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      return onCreateListItem.handler(snap, context, db)
    })
// The function successfully is invoked whenever a new document
// is added to the respective collection.
```

It serves to essentially put all documents in a list so that they can all be queried with only one read after the fact.
E.g. if I have 10 documents, the property `list` in the `items/list` document will have all 10 documents stored with their most relevant properties in an object. The array will be of length 10.
This is the most efficient way I can think of doing this, I am open to better suggestions.

My issue arises when there are no documents and the first one is added causing the `else` statement to run.
The `list` property then shows:
`'[{"value1":"one","value2":"two","value3":"three"},{}]'` in Firestore, when you would expect
`'[{"value1":"one","value2":"two","value3":"three"}]'`. I am not sure why this is happening.
When there is one item already in the list, and the `if` statement is `true` then it works as intended, i.e. adding each object to the end of the list.
I am using Firestore Cloud Functions with the respective emulator in addition to NodeJS16 in that environment.

Thanks in advance, I hope that the question is clearer for you all.

Comment: Mike, sorry to rollback, but the edit changed the code too much. `docRef.update` seems important to keep

Comment: The only thing it changed was "a function that no one can run" to "showing what it does when you run it", confronting the op with what their code actually does.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans apologies. SO edit said that `docRef.update({ list: JSON.stringify(list) })` was changed to `console.log({ list: JSON.stringify(list) })`

Comment: yes: `docRef.update` cannot be run by anyone, so by console logging the payload for that function instead, you (and op) can see what it's supposed to do by hitting "run". That's what runnable snippets are for. This then lets people go "the correct behaviour is what you're seeing in the browser, did you look up the firestorm docs for `docRef.update` to see what it does with arrays?".

Comment: And on that note, @aabdulahad: did you look up the firestorm docs for `docRef.update` to see what it does with arrays?

Comment: Sure thing. The issue likely lies with the function call. I'm just not sure logging the output (or using a snippet) helps demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Regardless of whether it can be run here, the question is specifically about what that function does. Removing it from the snippet makes the question nonsense.

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear, I have added an edit to clarify matters.

Comment: I suggest putting enough code and instructions here so that it's easy for anyone to copy it and observe the same results.  Make it as easy as possible for us to duplicate the unexpected behavior.  Right now you just have a small code snippet without saying exactly what you're doing to run and observe it, which leaves a lot to the imagination.

Comment: I have recreated the setup and tried to update a document using `docRef.update({ list: JSON.stringify(list) });`  and I am getting updated document field list saved as `[{"value1":"one","value2":"two","value3":"three"}]` and when used `docRef.update({ list: list })` I am getting updated document field list as Array with 0th element as Map of list which is intended. In my opinion there is no inconsistencies with using `JSON.stringify(list)` if you think I missed something please updated the question with adding more information.

Comment: Question completely rephrased, I have added the full function so it is easier to replicate.